# Get Windows user id in my node js so I can authenticate against ldap

Tags: node.js, authentication, ldap

I have developed a **nodejs intranet linux application** that can get a **username/email/phone** and other info based on the **Windows user id from a corporate ldap directory.**  The user enters their Windows user id in the browser to access the application and then I do a simple lookup in the ldap directory. Of course they can enter any user id because I don't ask for password (not an option at the moment) so there is a hole there.

I would like to have the logged in Windows userid be passed to my nodejs (or at least have the ability to forward it to ldap to get the userid).

Where do I start? I have googled but I can't find any specific answers.

**I have total control of of the intranet Linux server and if necessary i can implement an Apache/php solution.**

I would also like this to be useable from Chrome/Firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get detailed environment information like that from within the browser's javascript sandbox. If anything, you'd probably have to end up relying on some browser plugin (whether you write one yourself or use java/flash/etc) to get the information for you.

Comment: I don't want it from browser. I want it from the back end. Some kind of authentication has to occue but using Windows client credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There's an option to use Integrated Authentication with Apache and mod_auth_kerb.

See https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth

Answer (score 0):

I think [SPNEGO](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/SPNEGO-Authentication.html) could be useful for you.